# Responsive Height Spacing Between Elements

Tags: html, spacing

Hello I am trying to create a responsive layout. I want the buttons I have created to be fit somewhere on the left side. But when I load it on my mobile phone (sideways) it does not show all the buttons as I cannot scroll down. I don't want to have to scroll down. Can I make the size and/or spacing of the buttons dependent on the screen size?

Thank you!

http://farah-sean.samanthaongphoto.com/index2.html

Answer (score 0):

For responsiveness you can use 2 methods.

Or you base your CSS style based on percent and your layout will fit on the size screen, or you can define CSS rules based on screen size with CSS property @media

See exemple bellow from W3C [@media](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

Defining various @media for different screen size will make your layout responsive.